# JAVA Background Animation (LinearGradientPaint)

Tags: java, performance, graphics, awt, gradient

A LinearGradientPaint object from java.awt may appear nice once painted, but there's a problem I'm having with it for painting an animated background in some kind of game model that's taking me long to build.

I want to paint an animated rainbow gradient on the background using the Graphics2D paint object, except that when I do so, I notice a lot of lag in repainting the panel. It should repaint itself at least 30 frames per second, which is only possible if the Paint object the graphics object uses is not a rainbow gradient.

Even running it as a separate thread will not do the trick. Below is the code for what I am trying to do at the end of each frame:

```
gamePanel.executor.execute(new Runnable(){
        public void run()
        {
            while(true)
            {
                if (Background.selectedBackgroundIndex >= Background.SKY_HORIZON_GRADIENT_PAINT &&
                        Background.selectedBackgroundIndex < Background.SPACE_PAINT)
                {
                    float displacementValue = 1.0f;

                    if (Background.backgroundShape.y < ((-2990.0f) + CannonShooterModel.gamePanel.getSize().height) && gamePanel.horizonGoingDown)
                        gamePanel.horizonGoingDown = false;
                    else if (Background.backgroundShape.y > (-10.0f) && !gamePanel.horizonGoingDown)
                        gamePanel.horizonGoingDown = true;

                    Point2D.Double startPoint = (Point2D.Double)(((LinearGradientPaint)Background.background).getStartPoint()), 
                            endPoint = (Point2D.Double)(((LinearGradientPaint)Background.background).getEndPoint());

                    if (gamePanel.horizonGoingDown)
                        Background.backgroundShape.y -= displacementValue;
                    else
                        Background.backgroundShape.y += displacementValue;

                    startPoint.setLocation(0, Background.backgroundShape.y);
                    endPoint.setLocation(0, Background.horizonGradientPaintHeight + Background.backgroundShape.y);


                    // Should be done in another thread, particularly in arithmetic calculations.
                    Background.background = new LinearGradientPaint(startPoint, endPoint,
                            ((LinearGradientPaint)Background.background).getFractions(), 
                            ((LinearGradientPaint)Background.background).getColors());

                }

                for (int a = 0; a < PlayerUnit.weapon.bullets.length; a++)
                {
                    if (PlayerUnit.weapon.bullets[a] != null)
                    {
                        if (PlayerUnit.weapon instanceof Pistol &&
                                ((Ellipse2D.Float)PlayerUnit.weapon.bullets[a]).x + ((Pistol)PlayerUnit.weapon).bulletWidth >= 0 &&
                                ((Ellipse2D.Float)PlayerUnit.weapon.bullets[a]).x <= CannonShooterModel.gamePanel.getSize().width &&
                                ((Ellipse2D.Float)PlayerUnit.weapon.bullets[a]).y + ((Pistol)PlayerUnit.weapon).bulletWidth >= 0)
                        {
                            if (PlayerUnit.weapon.weaponAngles[a] >= 0)
                                ((Ellipse2D.Float)PlayerUnit.weapon.bullets[a]).x +=
                                        PlayerUnit.weapon.bulletSpeed * Math.cos(PlayerUnit.weapon.weaponAngles[a]);
                            else
                                ((Ellipse2D.Float)PlayerUnit.weapon.bullets[a]).x -=
                                    PlayerUnit.weapon.bulletSpeed * Math.cos(PlayerUnit.weapon.weaponAngles[a]);

                            if (PlayerUnit.weapon.weaponAngles[a] >= 0)
                                ((Ellipse2D.Float)PlayerUnit.weapon.bullets[a]).y -=
                                        PlayerUnit.weapon.bulletSpeed * Math.sin(PlayerUnit.weapon.weaponAngles[a]);
                            else
                                ((Ellipse2D.Float)PlayerUnit.weapon.bullets[a]).y +=
                                    PlayerUnit.weapon.bulletSpeed * Math.sin(PlayerUnit.weapon.weaponAngles[a]);
                        }
                        else
                            PlayerUnit.weapon.bullets[a] = null;
                    }
                }

                //System.out.println(Background.backgroundShape.y);

                repaint();

                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(1000 / 60);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException ex)
                {
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

The classes Background, PlayerUnit, and CannonShooterModel are important to my game model. It's an upright shooting game supposed to be designed with various weapons and enemies.

This rainbow gradient I have uses an array of eight different Color objects. For every frame passed through, I change the y-coordinate for both Point2D.Float objects required for the gradient paint as desired. In order for the animation to work, I have to actually instantiate another object of LinearGradientPaint again, with some of the previous properties from the previous object, and have it be referenced by the variable background of type Paint.

Problem is, LinearGradientPaint does not have a method to where you can do a translate on the two end points, and the get methods do not return the actual object that LinearGradientPaint object contains. (what I mean is, the get methods return a new object of Point2D with the same values as those part of the LinearGradientPaint object.)

For every frame passed, I have to change not only the y-coordinate property of the shape that's associated with the gradient, but also set the locations of the two Point2D objects that are needed to instantiate LinearGradientPaint once again.

I would love to re-explain this much simpler, because I can have trouble with some knowledge of English, even though this is my primary language. Please let me know if you need re-explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of solutions you might try.

Instead of filling the entire paintable area, you could create a `BufferedImage` whose width is `1` pixel and height equal to the area you want to fill (assuming you are fill vertically).  You would then apply the `LinearGradientPaint` to this `BufferedImage`'s `Graphics2D` and fill it (don't forget to dispose of the `Graphics` context when your done).

Then, you would simply use `Graphics#drawImage(Image, x, y, width, height, ImageObserver)` to actually paint the image.  Generally speaking, it appears that it's faster to rescale an image then it is to fill it with a `LinearGradientPaint`, especially when you consider you are only stretching the image horizontally.

The other choice would be to generate a basic `BufferedImage` which had the `LinearGradientPaint` already applied and you would simply paint this offset as required.  This would probably require you to paint it at least twice to allow it to "stitch" toegther...

Comment: Sounds plausible. Just one thing that I didn't make myself clear in my original description: (excuse me if I will always tend to talk about things that are sort of unclear. Or maybe I didn't understand your comment properly) the scroll I'm doing is actually vertical.

So, how do I do it? This is the first time I'm operating a BufferedImage with a LinearGradientPaint, and so I'm not sure on what code I must type to try this out. [you don't have to be exact, but it should be something I can learn from. I'm simply too occupied with other things.]

Comment: Sorry, that should read "vertically". The basic idea would be to create a BufferedImage the height of the range you want to move and simply offset the position of the image as you need, scrolling it...

Comment: Excuse me if I'm so busy with everything. I'm actually doing a full college semester for four months. Anyway, I'll try it out and see how it goes. In case I find something going wrong, I'll keep touch with you.

Comment: Okay, it looks like I am running into trouble with BufferedImage, because here's what I've put in:

if (backgroundImage == null)
{
backgroundImage = new BufferedImage(1, horizonGradientPaintHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    
Graphics2D g = backgroundImage.createGraphics();
   
g.setPaint(background);
g.fill(new Rectangle2D.Float(0, 0, CannonShooterModel.gamePanel.getSize().width, 
CannonShooterModel.gamePanel.getSize().height));

g.dispose();
}
I only get a grey screen with this setup. What am I missing? I am not familiar with BufferedImage... :(

Comment: You need to paint the BufferedImage to the component, using its paintComponent method and Graphics#drawImage

Answer (score 0):

If you are just making the background gradient move up and down, could you write it to an image at initialization and then move and **wrap** the image vertically?